# Program closes when trying to connect to IMAP

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

I'm having some strange IMAP library behavior. What I mean is: I'm trying to write my own service that will connect to a mail service and download some attachments from emails. Unfortunately, I ended up with a situation where I need to connect to IMAP with some settings. Before, I discovered some problems with socket errors and the need for SSL in my project. And now, when I set this all up, I have only 1 second pause on `IMAP.Connect`, and then the program just closes without any crashes or some info about it.

How can I continue the program?

Here is my code:

```
unit UMailWorker;

interface

uses Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdMessage, IdMessageCollection,
  IdAttachment,
  IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdMessageClient, IdIMAP4, IdSSLOpenSSL,
  IniFiles;

type
  TDownloadThread = class; // Предварительное объявление

  TMailWorker = class
  private
    FIMAP: TIdIMAP4;
    FMyThread: TDownloadThread;

  public
    procedure SetOptions;
    function InitWorker: Boolean;
    property IMap: TIdIMAP4 read FIMAP write FIMAP;
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

  TDownloadThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

uses UService;

{ TMailWorker }

constructor TMailWorker.Create;
begin
  FIMAP := TIdIMAP4.Create(nil);
  Self.SetOptions;
  Self.InitWorker;
  FMyThread := TDownloadThread.Create(False);
  FMyThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

destructor TMailWorker.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FIMAP) then
    FreeAndNil(FIMAP);
  if Assigned(FMyThread) then
    FMyThread.Terminate;
end;

function TMailWorker.InitWorker: Boolean;
var
  IniFile: TIniFile;
begin
  Result := False;
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Options.ini');
  try
    IMap.Username := IniFile.ReadString('Authenticacion', 'Email', '0');
    IMap.Password := IniFile.ReadString('Authenticacion', 'Password', '0');
    if (IMAP.Username <> EmptyStr) and (IMAP.Password <> EmptyStr) then
      Result := True;
  finally
    IniFile.Destroy;
  end;
end;

procedure TMailWorker.SetOptions;
begin
  FIMAP.Host := 'imap.gmail.com';
  FIMAP.Port := 993;
  FIMAP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  FIMAP.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IMap.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IMap.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
end;
{ TDownloadThread }

procedure TDownloadThread.Execute;
//var
//  MsgNums: TIdIMAP4SearchRec;

//  Msg: TIdMessage;
//  Attachment: TIdAttachment;
//  I, J: Integer;
//  AttachmentFileName: string;
begin
  inherited;
  repeat
  until (Assigned(MyService));

  if Assigned(MyService) and (pos('@', MyService.Worker.FIMAP.Username) <> 0)
    and (MyService.Worker.FIMAP.Username <> '') and
    (MyService.Worker.FIMAP.Password <> '') then
  begin
    with MyService.Worker do
    begin
      FIMAP.Connect;
      FIMAP.Login;

      FIMAP.SelectMailBox('INBOX');
      try
        // FIMAP.SearchMailBox(MsgNums, 'ALL');
      finally

      end;

    end;

  end;

end;

end.
```

I just try some things, try to reinstall SSL and something like that.

Comment: "*then the program just closes without any crashes or some info about it*" - you are not catching any of the exceptions that `TIdIMAP4` may raise at runtime (eg, unable to connect, SSL failure, IMAP login failure, etc). Any uncaught exception is going to terminate your thread (setting its `FatalException` property). If you want to know what is going on, catch the exception and look at its `ClassName` and `Message`.

Comment: On a side note, you should be setting your thread's `FreeOnTerminate` property *before* you let the thread start running. Otherwise, if it crashes before you have a chance to set it, the thread object would be leaked. Set `FreeOnTerminate` in the thread's constructor, or else create the thread with `CreateSuspended=True` and then `Start()` the thread after setting `FreeOnTerminate`.

Comment: You are accessing the FIMAP variable inside a thread without synchronize() while FIMAP is defined outside the thread. That's a big no-no in thread programming. BTW have you also looked in the Windows event-log to see if anything is there?

Comment: @Rik That is a big no-no for UI controls.  That is perfectly fine for non-visual components, like `TIdIMAP4`. Clearly there is only 1 IMAP object per thread, so synchronizing is not needed if code outside of the `MailWorker` is not directly accessing the IMAP object, which is not shown in this example. I do question `TMailWorker` exposing public access to its internal `TIdIMAP4` object, though...

Comment: @Remy Lebeau i wrapped TIDIMAP4.Connect with except on E: Exception do and nothing changes( only past situation - program shutting down without any bugs or exceptions

Comment: @blackspaceghost then you have a problem elsewhere in your code that we can't see. An exception raised in a TThread will not terminate the whole process. Even if you don't catch the exception, TThread will internally. So, something else is going on elsewhere to kill your program.